# Way to Avoid False Entries

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that adds records to a storage table if a feeder table has a new row added.
It works fine and doesn't produce errors.
There are times however when it adds records ***when no new row was added*** to the feeder table.

I was wondering what I would need to add to always confirm before adding a new record?

Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()


    Dim n As Long
    n = GetTableSize() '**GetTableSize monitors a static cell which calculates table number of used rows in a table. If that number is different than LastRowNumber...**
    If n > LastRowNumber Then NewDatabaseEntry **' NewDatabaseEntry adds new records
    ' Always set LastRowNumber so that even after entries are deleted (n < NumRows),
    ' adding new entries will work correctly.**
    LastRowNumber = n 'It then resets the values so they are equal again


End Sub
```

Sometimes, I'm working in the feeder table, and then I go check the records table and a new set of records has been added, even though no new rows were added.
Is there a way to add a message box that asks if you meant to add a new record and if you click no, it stops this from running?

I am currently getting errors for the code below. This could be a solution if I get it to work correctly right?

Comment: How can we *reproduce* your problem? We need a [mcve]

Comment: @CallumDa That is the problem! There is no problem a lot of the time until there is a problem. So I want this code to only run after a confirmation. I.E. put a pause in the automation. This problem will occur 1 in 25 times currently.

Comment: Please don't put answers in the question - you can self-answer your own question by posting an actual *answer* in the provided space below. Anything else defeats the Q&A nature of this site - Stack Overflow isn't some discussion forum where answers are in all kinds of random places; users *expect* to find answers under *answers*, and the OP is *expected* to contain a specific *question*. Take the [tour] if you haven't already. Cheers!

Comment: Saw the button below, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: SOLVED!!**

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

        Dim n As Long
        Dim rspn As VbMsgBoxResult

        rspn = MsgBox("Did you want to add a project?", vbYesNo)

    If rspn = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    'code
         n = GetTableSize()
        If n > LastRowNumber Then NewDatabaseEntry
        ' Always set LastRowNumber so that even after entries are deleted (n < NumRows),
        ' adding new entries will work correctly.
        LastRowNumber = n

    End Sub
```